# Как редактировать конфиг файлы и смотреть хэш в Windows контейнеров от Linux?

Tags: windows, phpstorm, docker

Я установил *Docker* на *Windows*. Он включен в режиме `Switched to Linux containers`.

Когда в консоли набираю `docker inspect e3a934c54979` мне отображается информация:

```
[
    {
        ...
        "Image": "sha256:2359fa12fdedef2af79d9b836a26175808d4b1433b5e7022d2d73c72b2a43b60",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8/e3a934c549799d9ec45d65ad6aa73bba8fad924215087a9c9c60535ef2a5c2e8-json.log",
        "Name": "/festive_edison",          
        ...
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f5348d5bfa76612ab30d1a253f17a6989fcd3f7ce23642b313c49f99a95f44-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/028eac1b0f37fd3be798d222f7d1da48a40f0ef9c4470709e63c4c8f322a477f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d15e7ce0f29f82d6d3b9537980b766c32e7f6ffc81374cdb26fede3872afed1e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/efab543606225e581832ef6e2b732a78c82b2f6d9fe662babe09b188f600dd72/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/263366359e8a86cc6c009f70fa00a158dbcbcfd2a4e31d9538c559dd82e29b10/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/32ea6c48b53f4846284e1baac83dffcfb039a53a8d2f33ac2728691160f5d100/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/685745d44609453debf484b2ccf63035532b334e75b9f18a00c5e1253e18841a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e30c0a304544255bc9eba90dfb720c332e168b4972df926a79ef27df707889fd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a5743532bc060895f0a495249182787322400a1a33fd187b3210895e1ca83129/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f5348d5bfa76612ab30d1a253f17a6989fcd3f7ce23642b313c49f99a95f44/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f5348d5bfa76612ab30d1a253f17a6989fcd3f7ce23642b313c49f99a95f44/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/10f5348d5bfa76612ab30d1a253f17a6989fcd3f7ce23642b313c49f99a95f44/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        ...
    }
]
```

Но в *Windows*, понятно, что нет таких директорий. Есть только "MobyLinuxVM.vhdx", в котором, на сколько я понял, и содержится всё.

Вопрос: Как можно в данном случае редактировать например "config.json" и "hostconfig.json"? как просмотреть GUID-json.log? Как посмотреть Хэши накатываемых слоев (`/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff`)?

Comment: http://pyatilistnik.org/kak-otkryit-vhd-i-vhdx-v-windows-server-2012-r2/ - не оно?

Comment: @donRumata может и оно, но пытаюсь сделать через "Подключить", пишет "образ диска не инициализирован" https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqnEO.jpg  .А если через "управление дисками" - подключается, появляется в нижнем списке, https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUURs.jpg  но всё что можно с ним сделать - отключить и всё. буквы нет. взглянуть на данные внутри негде.

Comment: А, ну хотя да. Логично. Там же внутри наверняка ext4. Мда. А вот этот проект попробуй: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/ . Минимум на чтение оно должно отработать.

Comment: @donRumata Не, не робит. Я вчера много гуглил. Скачивал программы:Ext2Fsd,linux-reader,ext2explore,linuxwin, но всё впустую. Пытался включить докер, запустить контейнер и уже с ним использовать программу - ноль. Может я криворукий, не знаю. Вообще, думал как вариант настроить как сетевой диск. Тоже долго мучился, делал через самбу (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way%21). Но в винде меня никуда не пускало. не сис админ я ни разу)

Comment: Про сетевой диск я глупость сморозил))

Comment: Как-то всё сложно. А не проще взять и поменять ОС? Потому что нативная платформа для запуска докера - всё-таки ни разу не винда.

Comment: От платформы на которой стоит докер ничего не меняется

Answer (score 1):

Команда `docker inspect`  отображает то как все огранизовано внутри контейнера. Можно посмотреть внутрений IP мосты и т.д. Если вы хотите редактировать файлы в контейнере то используйте команду `docker exec -ti container_name bash` чтобы попасть в контейнер и внутри редактировать или используйте флаг `-v` чтобы иметь доступ из контейнера к локальному файлу